# CMD doesn't update environment variables

Tags: windows-8.1, cmd.exe, path, environment-variables

When I edit the system environment variable PATH (or any other, I imagine) through `Control Panel\System and Security\System > Advanced system settings`, it doesn't update in CMD, even after restarting CMD or the computer.

I'm on Windows 8.1. I have admin privileges.

Comment: This [question](http://superuser.com/questions/668852/why-doesnt-environment-variable-get-updated-in-cmd-without-restart?rq=1) is related also [this](http://superuser.com/questions/800471/cmd-doesnt-update-environment-variables-even-when-restarting-the-os?rq=1) is related and here is some [helpful](http://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them) information and [this](http://superuser.com/questions/457343/modifying-the-path-environment-variable-is-not-working?rq=1) might come in handy.

Comment: Are you running the prompt with elevated privilages?

Comment: @Burgi Nope. I tried that and it worked. How do I get it to work without "run as admin"?

Comment: So running as admin solved the problem of you not being able to edit the environment variables, considering the potential for damage why would you **NOT** want to run it as an admin?

Comment: @Burgi Huh? What damage are you talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Burgi, just run as admin.